# Java Comparing Exact Image and locating it into new bigger image

Tags: java, image-processing

Is there a way or a library to locate a smaller image into a bigger image, given they have exact same size as with the new image.

here is a 512x512 image

[image]

and here is a 1000x1000 image

[image]

now the original 512x512 image is now located in the x(488) and y(488) of the new 1000x1000 image. is there a way that i can locate it programmatically?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[you may try OpenCV template matching](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatchtemplate/)

Comment: can you help me on how to use opencv in my netbeans project?

Comment: there's an example. of course, you'll have to adapt the code, but the algorithm is there - https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatchtemplate/?source=dlp

Comment: do you know where can i find an opencv jar?

Comment: I think there's no jar, but the src files seems to be here https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatchtemplate/files/jmatchtemplate/Version%200.5%20beta/ - notice that he generated different zips for windows and linux

Comment: I think there's some template matching here too https://java.net/projects/jaistuff/